# Does com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer support pipelining?

Tags: java, http, pipelining, com.sun.net.httpserver

Does com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer support single-connection pipelining? It seems to handle multiple clients in parallel, but a single connection's requests are being serially executed.

Is this accurate, and if so, is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP servers compliant to HTTP 1.1 are expected to support pipelining. Note that pipelining is supposed to be also supported by client.
According to [httpserver](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html)

> The API provides a partial
> implementation of RFC 2616 (HTTP 1.1)
> and RFC 2818 (HTTP over TLS).

it seems to imply that the `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` does not fully support HTTP1.1.
`HttpURLConnection` does not support pipelining and so I am leaning to think that the `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` does not support pipelining either.
You say you did some tests. How did you test this?

**Update**:
From the note it seems that pipelining is supported.
If, as you say you send the requests pipelined, the responses should come back according to the arrival of the requests (irrelevant of time it takes to finish each request i.e. some are faster than others).

Comment: I tested it by creating a server that handles two requests, one that sleeps, and one that doesn't, and a pipelined client. Creating two connections do not block each other (executed concurrently by the server), but a slow followed by a fast request on the same connection results in the fast waiting for the slow to finish. The documentation also adds, "Any HTTP functionality not provided by this API can be implemented by application code using the API." If you have any ideas on how best to approach this, I'd be thankful to hear them.

Comment: @Brian:If I understand correctly:you are using a pipelined client(your implementation?) and you are sending 2 requests over the same HTTP connection.One slow followed by one fast.I am not sure what you mean here, but on pipelining, if client send Req1,Req2 to the server, then the server is expected to send Response for Req1, followed by Response for Req2. I.e. the server MUST send the responses to the requests in the same order that the requests were received. So from your description, it seems that this is actually happening in your case, since the fast request was send after the slow.

Comment: I have tracing points in both requests to mark their start time and end times. What I always see is "START A; END A; START B; END B". Of course, what I'd like to see is "START A; START B; END A; END B" - and this happens if two different connections are issuing A and B, but not for the same.

Comment: @Brian:Didn't you say that you are using a pipelined client?Are you not sending the requests pipelined? Can you give more details on the client side implementation?Because your notes seem in contradiction so far.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP pipelining means something really simple: client can write next request to the connection without having read the previous response.

It's really difficult for any http server to not support pipelining. It has to look ahead, and if it finds bytes available beyond current request, it needs to abort ... but that's ridiculous, and nobody does it.

This has nothing to do with how requests are processed by server - serially or paralleled. Doing it in parallel is of course more difficult, and there are some questions that must be resolved.

Comment: The question was more in the context of the HttpServer class itself. The registered HttpHandler will be invoked serially for two pipelined requests, where, for every request, a HttpExchange object is given. It appears that it's not the case that two HttpExchanges can be outstanding for a single connection, even if the server is careful in responding in proper order.

Comment: @Brian per HTTP spec, the server is still supporting pipelining, even though internally requests are processed serially.